# How to restore a Git project to the last committed state using SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Somewhere I made a bunch of changes and I need to go back to an earlier version. I copied my current projects out of my local directory that contains the project. The project contains about 5 directories. I copied out two of them and then deleted those two folders.

I now need to reset back to an earlier version. I'm using SourceTree and need help to go back to the last commit. I double clicked on the tag and it shows this message:

[image]

I don't know what that means so I selected the second to top row and right clicked. It showed "Reset to master to this commit". I attached screen shots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I just want to reverse all my local changes at this point. Is this what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

In your second screenshot is a dropdown labeled "Using Mode"

If you do "Mixed" then everything you undo will be staged and ready to re-commit. This is a safer way to reset.

Alternatively, if you do "hard" then all changes will be deleted as if they never happened. IT sounds like you want to do that.

Another thing to note, when you reset an earlier commit it resets everything from current head all the way back.

After all of your work is done you'll need to do a force push. This isn't supported by SourceTree so you'll need to click the "Console" button at the top of the SourceTree window then type:

`git push origin -f`

WARNING - Don't do any of these steps if this is a team effort. Other developers will run into issues. This is true just about anytime you need to do a force push.

Comment: I mostly understood that, but I didn't want to mess anything up for other developers so I added the files and folders back into their original location. then I discarded all the changes manually one by one.

Comment: A solid rule of thumb is to never do a rebase on a public branch. Only on features branches.